# Is there a way to add metadata to all GET endpoints in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware, duende

In the following statement, the `AsBffApiEndpoint()` adds an attribute to all endpoints. Then there is a middleware specifically looking for that attribute and if present will check for an antiforgery header to be present.

`endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization().AsBffApiEndpoint();`

I need to be able to bypass that check on all GET endpoints. Most importantly, this is third party library, hence I have no control over the implementation.

I have try many things without success. Last attempt was to add a middleware custom middleware `app.Use(...)` and if the attribute was present, then remove it. However that's not possible since the list of metadata is `readonly`. Then, my last hope is to find a way to add same attribute -to all GET- with a flag `false` which ignores the check. In other words, all `AsBffApiEndpoint()` does is decorate an endpoint with `[BffApi]` attribute. This attribute ignores antiforery headers if use like this `[BffApi(false)]`. I know the solution is hacky because I will end up with something like this.

```
[BffApi]
[BffApi(false)]
//endpoint definition here
```

The good news is they get the endpoint metadata ordered `endpoint.Metadata.GetOrderedMetadata<BffApiAttribute>()`. Meaning as long as `[BffApi(false)]` takes priority in the list I should be good.

Comment: Hi @yopez83, what is your `AsBffApiEndpoint`? Did you use any other extension?

Comment: @Rena It's an implementation of the BFF pattern. https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/BFF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution and didn't involve adding a second attribute but to extend the builder rather. This way I could modify the endpoints metadata, which at that point are mutable.

```
public static TBuilder AsBffApiEndpointBypassAntiforgeryOnGET<TBuilder>(this TBuilder builder, string routePrefix) where TBuilder : IEndpointConventionBuilder
{
    builder.Add(endpointBuilder =>
    {
        var getAttribute = endpointBuilder.Metadata.FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetType() == typeof(HttpGetAttribute)) as HttpGetAttribute;
        var routeAttribute = endpointBuilder.Metadata.FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetType() == typeof(RouteAttribute)) as RouteAttribute;
        if (getAttribute != null && routeAttribute != null && routeAttribute.Template.StartsWith(routePrefix))
        {
            endpointBuilder.Metadata.Add(new BffApiAttribute(false));
        }
        else
        {
            endpointBuilder.Metadata.Add(new BffApiAttribute(true));
        }
    });

    return builder;
}
```

Then in `Startup.cs`

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapBffManagementEndpoints();
        endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization().AsBffApiEndpointBypassAntiforgeryOnGET("api/Foo");
    });
```

A more generic implementation would be the following.

```
public static IEndpointConventionBuilder AddConditionalMetadata(this IEndpointConventionBuilder builder, Func<EndpointBuilder, bool> evalEndpoint, Action<EndpointBuilder> onEvalTrue, Action<EndpointBuilder> onEvalFalse)
{
    builder.Add(endpointBuilder =>
    {
        if (evalEndpoint.Invoke(endpointBuilder))
        {
            onEvalTrue.Invoke(endpointBuilder);
        }
        else
        {
            onEvalFalse.Invoke(endpointBuilder);
        }
    });

    return builder;
}
```

This way you expose the function to evaluate and the actions to perform. Then, your `Startup.cs` will change to this.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapBffManagementEndpoints();
    endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization().AddConditionalMetadata(
        evalEndpoint: (endpointBuilder) => 
        {
            var routeAttribute = endpointBuilder.Metadata.FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetType() == typeof(RouteAttribute)) as RouteAttribute;
            var getAttribute = endpointBuilder.Metadata.FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetType() == typeof(HttpGetAttribute)) as HttpGetAttribute;
            return getAttribute != null && routeAttribute != null && routeAttribute.Template.StartsWith("api/Foo");
        }, 
        onEvalTrue: (endpointBuilder) => { endpointBuilder.Metadata.Add(new BffApiAttribute(false)); },
        onEvalFalse: (endpointBuilder) => { endpointBuilder.Metadata.Add(new BffApiAttribute()); });
});
```

I hope this can help someone else looking for the same thing.